# NDP6020P P-Channel MOSFET + ESP8266-01 Voltage Drop

Tags: mosfet, esp8266, voltage

I'm trying to power a ESP8266-01 with a NDP6020P.
My main power supply is a buck converter configured at 3.6V.
I connect the NDP6020P source to 3.6v and the Gate to Ground. If I calulcate the Drain voltage I get close to 3.6V (as expected). If I connect my ESP8266-01 to the Drain the Voltage drops to 2V. I tried increasing the buck converter to 4.2V I get the 3.7V when I connect the ESP8266-01.
Connecting the ESP direct on the Buck converter works fine. No voltage drop.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share a photo of your circuit?

Comment: Also, please save us all having to google the datasheets for these parts, and provide links.

Comment: Something is faulty (like your connections) if a 10A switch drops that much. Did it get hot?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info. Here is a picture of the circuit https://imgur.com/a/GzGpx5q and here is the NDP6020P datasheet https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NDP6020P-D.PDF

I know that there are more components to the picture but I also tried to rebuild it in a simpler form with the same results (without the attiny, the switch and the transistor).
When I press the button, I short the Mosfet and Power the circuit. ESP8266-01 is being fed by the Drain as you can see in the pictureThe attiny+transistor is there just to keep the Gate shorted for 10 seconds so please ignore it.